# Find files with the same name but different extensions and delete the oldest

Tags: command-line, delete

I have a folder with files like this:

```
1.jpg (Modified 2018-07-18 12:00:00)
1.png (Modified 2018-07-17 12:00:00)
2.jpg (Modified 2018-07-18 14:00:00)
3.jpg (Modified 2018-07-17 20:00:00)
4.jpeg (Modified 2018-07-17 12:00:00)
4.gif (Modified 2018-07-18 11:00:00)
4.png (Modified 2018-07-18 13:00:00)
```

And I need to have it like this:

```
1.jpg (Modified 2018-07-18 12:00:00)
2.jpg (Modified 2018-07-18 14:00:00)
3.jpg (Modified 2018-07-17 20:00:00)
4.png (Modified 2018-07-18 13:00:00)
```

Keep the newest files no matter the extension.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are all the files' names ascending numbers like in the example or are they "normal" names? Do you wanna use bash|find|ls|rm specifically or doesn't it matter? I find your question lacking specification of what you want to do and what you have tried!

Comment: Thanks for writing! I tried some stuff that I've found online but none of them were exactly what I need. The names are all numbers, for example: 9292939.jpg, 0392838384.png, etc. etc. I doesn't matter if the solution involve bash (what I tried), find, ls. I just need to delete duplicated file names but keeping the newer. That's it.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a program doing that. I could try writing something like that in bash (or different programming lang. I know), but it won't be very elegant. Are the files in one folder, one folder and its subfolders or different folders completely?

Comment: I need to do this just one time. Then an admin module will take care of duplicates by deleting an older file when a new one is uploaded. The files are in one folder and there are no subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a short bash script. 
It takes all non-folder files in a folder (from which it is executed) and moves the older files with same name to folder.

 I named the folder "remove_##" where ## is a number.
The names of files are taken as same if they are same before the last dot! e.g. *123.png* is taken as same as *123.jpg* but not as *123.tar.gz*.

If two (or more) files have same modification time than the script preserves the first one it encountered and writes a message to output. 
It shouldn't do anything bad if you use it in right folder!

**remove_older.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOVE_FOLDER="remove_"$$
mkdir $REMOVE_FOLDER

ls --color=never -p | grep -v / | sed "s;\..*;;g" | sort -n | uniq  | \
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do 
    time=0   # currently a youngest mtime of files with $line name
    newest=0 # currently a youngest file with $line name

    for file in $line.* ; do
        mtime=`stat -c %Y $file` # reads mtime of $file
        if [[ "$mtime" -gt "$time" ]]; then # we found younger file
            time=$mtime
            newest=$file
        elif [[ "$mtime" -lt "$time" ]]; then # we found older file
            mv $file $REMOVE_FOLDER
        else  # files have same modification time -> does nothing
            echo "File $file has same modification time as $newest!"
        fi
    done

    if [[ "$newest" != 0 ]]; then # we found some files!
        for file in $line.* ; do
            if [[ $file != $newest ]]; then
                mv $file $REMOVE_FOLDER # remove older file 
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```